# How to save .m3u8 file to local disk in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a file with .m3u8 format that I can play and can also cache to later play it offline using the below code:

```
    class DownloadManager: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = DownloadManager()
    
    func setupAssetDownload(url:URL) {
        //
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "streamVideo")
        let downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                                        assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let downloadTask = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                                 assetTitle: "",
                                                                 assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                                 options: nil)
        downloadTask?.resume()
    }
}

extension DownloadManager: AVAssetDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(location.relativePath, forKey: "assetPath")
    }
}
```

And later play it like this:

```
   guard let assetPath = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "assetPath") as? String else {
         // Present Error: No offline version of this asset available
         return
     }
     let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
     let assetURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(assetPath)
     let asset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
        if let cache = asset.assetCache, cache.isPlayableOffline {
            let avItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avItem)
            player?.play()
    }
```

But how can I save this to local disk so that user can share/download it while playing?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the current issue?

Comment: There are many ways to write/save to a file, using `.fileExporter(....)` or
 with `FileManager` and `try somedata.write(to: fileURL)` etc... or
 using `Transferable` and `TransferRepresentation`. Do some more searching,
 this has been done before. What have you tried?